# React-Native - react-native-update-gradle - Error

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

i had an error with my React-Native Project for Android.

My first error was the following:

I added the "react-native-location" Library. After i run the Command "react-native link", the error "compileOnly" was thrown.
So my first try was, upadate NPM and Node.JS.
But it wasn´t the right solution for my Problem.

After that, i had google the Error and i want to update grandle with "react-native-update-gradle". My main Problem now is, when i run the "react-native link" command, i get the following error:

```
    C:\Computer\Apps\Projects\XXX>react-native link
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Computer\Apps\Projects\XXX\node_modules (70ms)
rnpm-install info Platform 'ios' module react-native-orientation is already linked
rnpm-install info Platform 'android' module react-native-orientation is already linked
internal/validators.js:125
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:427:7)
    at getSDKPath (C:\Computer\Apps\Projects\XXX\node_modules\react-native-update-gradle\index.js:13:12)
    at getPTPath (C:\Computer\Apps\Projects\XXX\node_modules\react-native-update-gradle\index.js:17:20)
    at Object.activateADB (C:\Computer\Apps\Projects\XXX\node_modules\react-native-update-gradle\index.js:5:42)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Computer\Apps\Projects\XXX\node_modules\react-native-update-gradle\cli.js:101:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
C:\Computer\Apps\Projects\XXX\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\core\makeCommand.js:27
        throw new Error(`Error occurred during executing "${command}" command`);
        ^

Error: Error occurred during executing "node ./node_modules/react-native-update-gradle/cli.js" command
    at ChildProcess.prelink (C:/Computer/Apps/Projects/XXX/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/makeCommand.js:27:15)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:978:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
```

I tried to fix the Error, but the error is still there.

I had the following Environments

- Window 10
- React-Native 0.55.4
- React-Native-Cli 2.0.1
- NodeJS v11.9.0
- npm 4.6.0

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion   = 28
    targetSdkVersion    = 28
    buildToolsVersion   = "28.0.3"
    supportLibVersion   = "28.1.1"
    playServicesVersion = "15.0.1"
}
```

**package.json**

```
 {
  "name": "XXX",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "run-android": "react-native run-android"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-image-slider": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^2.2.25",
    "react-native-orientation": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-pinch-zoom-view": "^0.1.6",
    "react-native-responsive-image": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.28",
    "react-native-scrolltotop": "0.0.6",
    "react-native-slideshow": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-update-gradle": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-native-zoom-view": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

If you need more information to help me, please tell me that.

Thanks for your help.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Hi [Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7370910/sebastian-h%C3%B6ck) ! After you run the command `react-native link`, you have to run the command `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios`. So that the library you have installed adjusts to your react native settings. This is work for me, after I installed the library or package. hope this helps.